# Add custom attributes to menu items without plugin

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add custom menu attributes without using a plugin. I have a site using a custom theme and need to make sure this is setup at theme activation vs needing to setup a plugin as well.

Is there a function I can plug into for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filter `nav_menu_link_attributes`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse_100726_extra_atts', 10, 3 );

function wpse_100726_extra_atts( $atts, $item, $args )
{
    // inspect $item, then …
    $atts['custom'] = 'some value';
    return $atts;
}
```

This works with WordPress < 3.6:

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', function( $item ) {

    $parts = explode( '>', $item );
    $out   = array ();

    foreach ( $parts as $i => $part )
    {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $part, '<a ' ) ) // a start
            $out[ $i ] = $part . ' data-foo="bar"';
        else
            $out[ $i ] = $part;
    }

    return join( '>', $out );
});
```

Comment: I was surprised to see this filter as I had just been reading the nav menu source code and did not notice it. It is in the beta version 3.6.0 but not in the production version 3.5.1. The old filter 'walker_nav_menu_start_el' might also work.

Comment: I've tried adding this function into my code, but for some reason it's not doing anything. Is there additional code I need to write for it?

Comment: @JakeLisby Sorry, the first code I posted works in 3.6 only. I made an update with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

it is nice work. but i want to little bit extra more, trying but can not figure out yet how.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse_100726_extra_atts', 10, 3 );

function wpse_100726_extra_atts( $atts, $item, $args )
{
    // inspect $item, then …
    $atts['data-hover'] = 'some value';
    return $atts;
}
```

i want some value change to menu items name. ex **data-hover="contact us"**

Comment: this is the wrong place to ask for support. ask your own question or never get an answer. besides, your code works just fine.